# display data in a loop using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the markers longitude and latitude and display them on the map but I'm not getting any result, my parser.php file is working and fetching the data from the database i just need to format it into javascript anyone ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922},
      zoom: 14
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    $.getJSON('parser.php', function(items) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            (function(item) {
                addMarker(item.lat, item.lon);
            })(items[i]);
        }
    });

    }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

parser.php output

```
[{"0":"33.880561","lat":"33.880561","1":"35.542831","lon":"35.542831"},{"0":"-25.363882","lat":"131.044922","1":"35.513477","lon":"35.513477"}]
```

Comment: It would help to see a sample of the JSON object returned by `parser.php`.

Comment: Doesn't `addMarker` need to take the `map` as an argument?

Comment: @Barmar sorry first time i use $.getJSON I'm not sure if I'm using it the correct way, though google maps documentation shows the following adding a marker snippet,

`var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.890537,35.513477);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
 });`

Comment: So put that code in the `for` loop.

Comment: What @Barmar said, or define an `addMarker()` function with the code you quoted.

Comment: @Alfonso can you please show me how ?

Answer (score 1):

`addMarker` needs to take `map` as an argument.

```
function addMarker(map, lat, long) {
    var latlong = google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlong,
        map: map
    });
}
```

Then your loop should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    item = items[i];
    addMarker(map, item.lat, item.lon);
}
```

You don't need to put the `addMarker` calls into a closure, because these aren't separate callbacks.

Comment: can you tell me what I'm doing wrong cause i can't seem to make it work, 
`function addMarker(map, lat, long) {
var latlong = google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
return new google.maps.Marker({
 position: latlong,
 map: map
});
}

$.getJSON('parser.php', function(items) {
 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  (function(item) {
   addMarker(map, item.lat, item.lon);
  })(items[i]);
 }
});`

Comment: You didn't put `map` in the arguments to `addMarker`.

Comment: Don't put long code blocks in comments, there's no formatting.

Comment: I've never used the Google Maps API, so I was just going by what you wrote. If that was correct, then my code should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66832/discussion-between-karma-cat-and-barmar).

Comment: Sorry, not interested in prolonging this.